# Best way to design multple and nested GET/POST in QT with QNetworkManager

Tags: c++, qt, post, get, qnetworkaccessmanager

the doubt i have is about the correct design of a software which implements multiple and nested GET/POST request.

Say you have to run a login() function which requires a GET and a POST and then retrieveXYZ() which requires two GETs (and so on, scalable).

The way i was thinkig to do it was like

```
mainwindow.cpp
    //code
    login();
    retrieveXYZ();
    //code

Mainwindow::login(){ 
    //code
    connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onGetLoginFinished()));
    nam->get(...);
}

Mainwindow::onGetLoginFinished(){
    //do stuff
    connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onPostLoginFinished()));
    nam->post(...);
}    

Mainwindow::onPostLoginFinished(){
    //do stuff
}

Mainwindow::retrieveXYZ(){
    //code
    connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onGet1RetrieveFinished()));
    nam->get();
    //code
}

Mainwindow::onGet1RetrieveXYZFinished(){
    //do stuff
    connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onGet2RetrieveFinished()));
    nam->get();
}
```

or should i use something like QSignalMapper ?
Which are the most correct/efficient way to do so? i've seen people using sender() cast but i didn't understand the point.

Basically i would like to retrieve the particular reply finished() signal rather than the general one (or of the qnam)

This method may work but it is not nice and clean to me

Is this the best we can get?

http://www.johanpaul.com/blog/2011/07/why-qnetworkaccessmanager-should-not-have-the-finishedqnetworkreply-signal/

Moving the connect approach to the reply?

Comment: Do you have several `QNetworkAccessManager` ? Which part is in serial/parallel ?

Comment: I only have one QNetworkAccessManager, what do you mean with serial/parallel? I have no parallel request, i only have serials. The problem is that they are different depending on the tasks. Login() function is an example of a GET followed by a POST

Comment: So you want only blocking request ?

Comment: Rather than blocking i would like to perform different tasks depending of the kind of request im issueing and in which function... when i issue a GET the function to use will change depending in which condition i requested it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got something like:

```
struct RequestResult {
    int httpCode;
    QByteArray content;
};

RequestResult
ExecuteRequest(const std::function<QNetworkReply*(QNetworkAccessManager&)>& action,
               const std::chrono::milliseconds& timeOut)
{
    QEventLoop eLoop;
    QTimer timeOutTimer;
    QNetworkAccessManager nam;

    QObject::connect(&timeOutTimer, &QTimer::timeout, &eLoop, &QEventLoop::quit);
    QObject::connect(&nam, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, &eLoop, &QEventLoop::quit);

    timeOutTimer.setSingleShot(true);
    timeOutTimer.setInterval(timeOut.count());
    timeOutTimer.start();

    auto resetTimeOut = [&timeOutTimer]() { timeOutTimer.start(); };
    QNetworkReply* reply = action(nam);

    QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::uploadProgress, resetTimeOut);
    QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::downloadProgress, resetTimeOut);

    eLoop.exec();

    if (!timeOutTimer.isActive())
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Time out"); // Probably custom exception
    }
    const int httpStatus
        = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::Attribute::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
    auto content = TakeContent(*reply); // reply->readAll and decompression

    return RequestResult{httpStatus, content};
}
```

And then functions for get/delete/post/.. which are similar to

```
auto RequestGet(const QNetworkRequest& request) {
    return ExecuteRequest([&](QNetworkAccessManager& nam) { return nam.get(request); },
                          timeOut);
}

auto RequestDelete(const QNetworkRequest& request) {
    return ExecuteRequest([&](QNetworkAccessManager& nam) {
                              return nam.deleteResource(request);
                          },
                          timeOut);
}

auto RequestPost(const QNetworkRequest& request, QHttpMultiPart& multiPart)
{
    return ExecuteRequest([&](QNetworkAccessManager& nam) {
                              return nam.post(request, &multiPart);
                          },
                          timeOut);
}
```

Then, for your code, I would do something like

```
Mainwindow::login()
{
    const auto getRes = RequestGet(..);
    // ...
    const auto postRes = RequestPost(..);
    // ...
}
```

And you may use *thread* and *future* if you want not blocking calls.